# JS Flow: How to initialize an empty object and set type as an argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React reducer that sets an active user which is an object.  I want the initial state to be an empty object, `{}`.  However, I cannot figure out the syntax. This is my attempt:

```
// @flow
import { SET_ACTIVE_USER } from '../actions/types';

type action = {
  type: string,
  payload: Object,
};

const state: Object = {};

export default (state: state, action: <action>) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_ACTIVE_USER:
      return action.payload;
  }

  return state;
}
```

I have also tried doing this: 
`(state: Object = {}, action: <action>)` but it doesn't work either.

This is the full error message from running `flow`:

`12: export default (state: state, action: <action>) => {
                                 ^ Unexpected token ,`

Another attempt was to mimic the parameter that's working like this:

```
// @flow
...

type state = {};

export default (state: <state>, action: <action>) : Object => {
...
```

I have read through the documentation but I cannot find out the right syntax.

I had a syntax error elsewhere and fixing it along with converting it to this appears to have worked. Unsure of why that would be the case.

`export default (state: Object = {}, action: action) : Object => {`

So, I guess my question becomes, what is the **right** way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion `state` is of type `any`. The type `Object`, for example, doesn't have a member `a` (that in this case is just an example).

```js
/* @flow */

type state = {
  [key: string] : any
};

type ACTION_TYPE = string;

interface action {
    type: ACTION_TYPE,
    payload: any
}

export default (action: action, state: state): state => {

    return { a: '' };
};
```

---

> edits
>   `type state = any` could be even `type state = {[key: string]: any}` because is always true to assert that is an object with their keys of type string.

[edits declaring `state` as `Object`: try to have a look at this playground](https://tryflow.org/?code=LyogQGZsb3cgKi8KCgp0eXBlIEFDVElPTl9UWVBFID0gc3RyaW5nOwoKdHlwZSBzdGF0ZSA9IHsKICBba2V5OiBzdHJpbmddIDogYW55Cn07CgppbnRlcmZhY2UgYWN0aW9uIHsKICAgIHR5cGU6IEFDVElPTl9UWVBFLAogICAgcGF5bG9hZDogYW55Cn0KCmV4cG9ydCBkZWZhdWx0IChhY3Rpb246IGFjdGlvbiwgc3RhdGU6IHN0YXRlKTogc3RhdGUgPT4gewoKICAgIHJldHVybiB7IGE6ICcnLCBiOiAxMjMsIGM6IHt9LCBkOiBbXSwgZTogbmV3IERhdGUoKSB9Owp9Ow==)

Comment: Thank you. First time using Flow or any type system in JS.  This is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try `const state: {[string]: mixed}`. [(Object as map)](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps)

You should avoid using `any` https://flow.org/en/docs/types/any/#toc-avoid-leaking-anybecause it's easy to leak.

That said, you should probably be providing a complete initial state to your reducer. If you go this route and want to know about using Flow with Redux, there's good docs on the topic [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/).